# Changing scale of overall pdf document to 70%

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I want to create a PDF document with scale 70% from original (for A5 printing purposes)

Since I have always created usual pdf documents with A4 layout, I do not have a clue how to achieve this. I see two solutions:

- Is it possible to create this document directly from pdflatex? (in order not to loose quality)
- The other option is, of course, to create the document from the normal pdf file itself (A4) [gotten from pdflatex] by changing the option to 70% in adobe acrobat. Does this affect the overall quality?

Do you have any tips?

Comment: why don't you make use of `a5paper` in `geometry` package?

Comment: it isn't really a matter of quality rather than intent. If the intent is to have a "normal" page worth of text but shrink to a5 for portability (or blow up to a0 poster to read at a distance) typeset at a4 and just scale the pdf. If on the other hand you want normal sized text but less text on a5 (or a lot more on a conference poster to be read from close up) use the `geometry` package to typeset at the specified page size.

Comment: No, what I want is exactly the A4 normal content to be shrunk to A5 (the goal is to print it in a A5 book), but the document I have to submit to the publisher must be already in A5 format. And I was wondering if the second option I mentioned (easiest one) , changes the original quality

Comment: change of quality: for fonts no (assuming you use scalable fonts) for images probably not. If you have images generated for the exact pixel resolution used for print then scaling the document obviously causes some sampling to have to take place, however if you make the smaller document with `\includegraphics[width=...` then the images are scaled in any case and it won't make any real difference whether it's done in latex or in your printer driver.

Comment: @Claude A subscript or a footnote in 8pt in A4 will be unreadable reduced to A5!

Comment: @Paul Right I have already thought og it, I have no foot notes. Just normal text with 12pt and a lot of figures

Comment: you can try with `\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a5paper]`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply run this on the command line (assuming you have texlive/mactex on Linux or Mac):

```
pdfjam --outfile goodclaude.pdf --paper a5paper badclaude.pdf
```

Comment: I will try this

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: not used to compile the document with lines, i have to learn it first